# Good "handwritten" font for sketchy modus in Pencil Project

Tags: fonts

I am really quite impressed by the ["Pencil Project"](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) for generating mockups. One of the big advantages are the "sketchy" forms. In the [screenshots on the homepage](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/ScreenShots/ShotDetail.aspx?DocumentPath=screenshots/shots/sketchy-stencil) they are using the font ["Hand of Sean"](http://www.dafont.com/hand-of-sean.font), which is quite nice, but looks a little bit too "untidy" and "hard to read" (at least for me). Additionally it is not free for commercial use.

The font pencil is using on my pc is Comic Sans, which looks quite nice, but - we all know - it's Comic Sans.

Do you have got any good ideas for fonts I could use for this (preferebly with German Umlaute (äöü)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Segoe Print](http://www.ascenderfonts.com/font/segoe-print-regular.aspx) is a nice handwritten font to read in my opinion. It is included in all recent Windows versions and covers Basic Latin, Greek and Cyrillic.
[image: Sample text in Segoe Print: This is some text with ümläüts.]